# Passing an int variable to another activity makes the app crash,using putExtras

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a specific int variable through to another class but it crashes the program. Please have a look:

**First activity**

```
public void highQuiz(View view){

    Intent j= new Intent(this,HighScoreTable.class);

    j.putExtra("new_variable_name",(int)lowerInt);


    startActivityForResult(j, 0);   }
```

**Second activity**

```
    TextView hs1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int lowerInt= extras.getInt("new_variable_name");
        hs1.setText(""+lowerInt);
    }
```

**Log**

```
04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Process: oxley.It, PID: 2104

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{oxley.It/oxley.It.HighScoreTable}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at oxley.It.HighScoreTable.onCreate(HighScoreTable.java:25)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)

04-29 18:36:21.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: What do you mean it "crashes" - if it's throwing an exception, what exception?  If it's causing the JVM to BSD, then there's something really wrong...

Comment: When I go to the second activity, the app on the android emulator stops responding and needs to be closed

Comment: can you post the crash report?

Comment: have you getting application not responding dialog ? or the application is crashing?

Comment: getIntent.getIntExtra("new_variable_name") try this

Comment: and also share stack trace

Comment: I added the log to the post. I'll try the other solutions now

Comment: posted one answer try it

Comment: Edited : From the stack posted it is clear that lowerInt was null. The getIntExtra solution suggested should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
         if(getIntent().hasExtra("new_variable_name"))      
                  getIntent().getIntExtra("new_variable_name");
```

Comment: Where would i exactly put this?

Comment: oncreate of other activity

Answer (score 1):

From stack track looks like textview is null

```
    TextView hs1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Make sure you have defined the textview and its not null after you do findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

While starting the activity you are keeping that integer value in intent. and while reading in second activity you are getting it from Bundle which is inside the intent so you are not getting.
so read that integer value from intent.

```
TextView hs1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Intent i=getIntent();
i.getIntExtra("new_variable_name",0);
hs1.setText(""+lowerInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **First Activity** 

change

```
j.putExtra("new_variable_name",(int)lowerInt);
```

to

```
j.putExtra("new_variable_name",lowerInt);
```

No need to Parse value to integer.
and then in you **Second Activity**

Change 
`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int lowerInt= extras.getInt("new_variable_name");
        hs1.setText(""+lowerInt);
    }`

to

```
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getIntExtra();
if (extras != null) {
    int lowerInt= extras.getIntExtra("new_variable_name");
    hs1.setText(String.valueOf(lowerInt));
}
```